# How to iterate a loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a json variable

```
 var a = { Account: [ 'Name', 'Site', 'BillingState', 'Phone', 'Type', 'Owner.Alias' ],
```

Contact: [ 'Name1', 'Site1' ] }

and i am iterating loop like this

> ```
> app.post('/', function (req, res) {
> a = req.body.table_structure
> b = createSelectQuery(a)  res.send(b) // this return only "FROM CONTACT" })
> ```

Where i have created another function hoping i could in return get the desired string but the loop went async

```
function createSelectQuery(a){
        var selectQuery = "Select " 
        var obj = JSON.parse(a);
        for (var c in obj){
            for (var d in obj[c]){
                selectQuery += obj[c][d] + ', '
            }
            selectQuery = "FROM "+c
        }
        return selectQuery
    }
```

> I am expecting result "SELECT Name, .. etc from Account but getting
>   only FROM Account as output

Comment: What is `u'Account'`?

Comment: You json is in wrong format. It should have key and value to iterate.

Comment: @digit it's in json format

Comment: @user23323. Check out my answer below and verify if it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function createSelectQuery(a){
    var selectQuery = "Select "; 
    var obj = JSON.parse(a);
    for (var c in obj) {
        selectQuery += obj[c].join(", ") + " FROM " + c;
    }
    return selectQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use callback which will make your looping synchronous

Comment: i dont have much knowledge about it i am a beginner to nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I belive because in JSON file 'Account' is array and you try to loop in to it as if it was an object. Try :

```
function createSelectQuery(a){
        var selectQuery = "Select " 
        var obj = JSON.parse(a);
        for (var c in obj){
            for (var d=0; d < obj[c].length; d++){
                selectQuery += obj[c][d] + ', '
            }
            selectQuery = "FROM "+c
        }
        return selectQuery
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loop, you can try join the string using arr.join() and then append the string with Object.keys. That will do the trick

```js
var selectQuery = "Select ";
    var a = { Account: [ 'Name', 'Site', 'BillingState', 'Phone', 'Type', 'Owner.Alias' ]};
    var obj = a;
    var arr = obj['Account'];
    var joinStr = arr.join(',').toString();
    selectQuery = selectQuery +" "+joinStr +" FROM "+Object.keys(a);
    console.log(selectQuery);
```